# Is it a bad practice to mount network/slow shares under `/Volumes`?

Tags: macos, itunes, performance, mount, automount

I'm using curlftpfs with macfuse to mount some ftp sites through `automount`. The mount directories for each share is in `/Volumes` folder. Now iTunes on each startup tries to read `/Volumes/Curlftpfs_Share` and hangs.

Is it a bad practice to mount network/slow shares under `/Volumes`, where should I mount it instead?

Why does iTunes check all mounted shares on startup — can I switch it off?

Comment: I don't think it matters where you mount them as far as bad/good practise goes. I often see Linux setups with mounts mainly in `/mnt`. I guess iTunes takes the liberty of scanning it because it assumes it's a locally attached volume. Just create a directory somewhere that suits you and mount it there. Or, if this is hanging for when it's not connected, adjust the timeout in your `automount` configs.

Comment: I agree with *CraftyThumber*, I think it's perfectly OK (and even best practice on Macs) to mount network drives under `/Volumes`. Think that OS X also mounts them there. I don't have a silver bullet to solve the problem you describe... I've read that starting iTunes while holding down the Option/Alt key and explicitly selecting the path to your library may help.